# algorithm writer of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm writing an algorithm that provides a tkinter program as output (I hope I explained myself) the program works by dragging the combobox, the text ... into a space and memorizing the coordinates.
I decided to do it with pygame, (I took the skeleton of the program from the internet and then modified it).
I have encountered several problems:

- I have a problem inserting multiple images (for now I have only
  inserted one),
- I can't memorize the coordinates, I tried with print (event) but it doesn't work,
- I can not insert the image in a specific point of the root.

here is my code:

```
import os,sys
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
a=0
b=0
c=200
d=200
event = pg.event.poll()
Sfondo = pg.image.load("Sfondo.jpg")


def DisegnaBackground (a,b):
    Screen.blit(Sfondo,(a,b))


class Character:

    def __init__(self,rect):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(rect)
        self.click = False
        self.image = pg.image.load("ComboBox.png").convert()
        Screen.blit(self.image, (c,d))

    def update(self,surface):
        if self.click:
            self.rect.center = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        surface.blit(self.image,self.rect)


def main(Surface,Player):
    game_event_loop(Player)
    DisegnaBackground (a,b)
    Player.update(Surface)


def game_event_loop(Player):
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if Player.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                Player.click = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            Player.click = False
        elif event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit(); sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pg.init()
    Screen = pg.display.set_mode((1500,800))
    MyClock = pg.time.Clock()
    MyPlayer = Character((0,0,200,24))
    MyPlayer.rect.center = Screen.get_rect().center
    while 1:
        main(Screen,MyPlayer)
        pg.display.update()
        MyClock.tick(60)

        print(event)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems. First, try to make sure not to mix global and local variables. Try re-writing the function like this:

```
def DisegnaBackground (surface, a, b):
    surface.blit(Sfondo, (a, b))
```

For this to work, you have to update your main too:

```
def main(Surface,Player):
    game_event_loop(Player)
    DisegnaBackground (Surface, a, b)
    Player.update(Surface)
```

Finally, you do not need to display your character immediately after the creation, so you can leave the init function as

```
    def __init__(self,rect):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(rect)
        self.click = False
        self.image = pg.image.load("ComboBox.png").convert()
```

I hope it helps.